# Move cursor back to previous window after splitting

Tags: cursor-movement, vim-windows, split

After running a command that opens a new split (e.g. `:botright 10new`), how can I have the cursor move back to its previous position? A use case would be to show a message in a scratch buffer without moving out of the current file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`:h :wincmd`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd) to go to the previous window with [`:h CTRL-W_p`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL%2DW_p), leaving your cursor where you were before the split.

Following your example, to create a window 10 lines tall at the bottom of the tab, then return to the previous cursor position:

```
:botright 10new | wincmd p
```

Comment: Easier is `wincmd p` here, since you're in command-line mode already...

Comment: @filbranden Thanks, I've edited my answer.